# ssas mdx query unable to parser for ambiguity

Tags: sql-server-2012, mdx

I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2012 and the database Adventures Works.

I have written this mdx query:

```
SELECT
    {
        (
            [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]
        )
    } on axis(0),
    {
        (
            [Geography].[Country].Children,
            [Product].[Category].[Accessories]
        )
    },
    {
        (   
            [Geography].[Country].Children,
            [Product].[Category].[Bikes]
        )
    } on axis(1)
from [Adventure Works];
```

but the response is the following:

```
Executing the query ...
Parser: The statement dialect could not be resolved due to ambiguity.
Execution complete
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the following?

```
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]} ON 0
 ,
    [Geography].[Country].Children
  * 
    {
      [Product].[Category].[Accessories]
     ,[Product].[Category].[Bikes]
    } ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Or this:

```
SELECT
    {
        (
            [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]
        )
    } on axis(0),
    {
        (
            [Geography].[Country].Children,
            [Product].[Category].[Accessories]
        )
    ,

        (   
            [Geography].[Country].Children,
            [Product].[Category].[Bikes]
        )
    } on axis(1)
from [Adventure Works];
```

---

**Error Message**

The dialect error you're getting is due to the comma:

```
SELECT
    {
        (
            [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]
        )
    } on axis(0),
    {
        (
            [Geography].[Country].Children,
            [Product].[Category].[Accessories]
        )
    },  //<<<<<EXTRA COMMA HERE
    {
        (   
            [Geography].[Country].Children,
            [Product].[Category].[Bikes]
        )
    } on axis(1)
from [Adventure Works];
```

Comment: (feel free to hit the tick if it answers your question)